# Android relase APK can't load activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Using Android Studio 2.2, switching activities in my application works perfectly when I use the debug version. However, when I publish my application to the Google Play, I can open the application, but trying to start any other activities (via Intent) will crash the application.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.ddns.opencratebox.mycratebox"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.0.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.ddns.opencratebox.mycratebox">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="MyCrateBox"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".source.MVC.View.LaunchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".source.MVC.View.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".source.MVC.View.LoggedActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The only permission I am asking for is INTERNET, and I declared it. Anyway, it has nothing to do with starting activities. I have no idea what is going on, because debug version works so greatly (installing it via USB cable directly from android studio to my Tablet) Many friends tried it too and same result.

So, it does not work if I install it through Google play, but works if I install it via USB from Android Studio.

Anyone has an idea?

P.S. Already tried to put minifyEnabled to false, no results :( I heard that Proguard could remove constructors or piece of code, something like that.

**EDIT**
Stack trace of the crash event:

09-19 20:42:55.127 31614-31614/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process:

> net.ddns.opencratebox.mycratebox, PID: 31614
>                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   registerView(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick
>   attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'txvc_register'
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
>                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

The code that should start the other activity:

```
protected void registerView(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The XML that represents the click button:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvc_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_register"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:onClick="registerView"
        android:text="@string/or_register"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material" />
```

Comment: Did you test the release apk before uploading to the Play Store?

Comment: you can install the release app with adb install -r myapp.apk and connect the debugger and check the logcat you will have information why its crashing.

Comment: I did test the apk, but after the first release (Didn't know we could do that yet) I will try that surya thank you!

Comment: In Android Studio, open the Build Variants window and select the release version. Now you can run the released app directly on your test device or emulator. Once you do this, you can test the release build. You can also view the logcat in Android Studio to determine what the error is. If you need further help, please post the full stacktrace that you find in the logcat.

Comment: Found the log, edited in post. 'txvc_register' is the button I clicked that should start another activity.

Comment: in the xml you have used onClick defined to a function can you check the xml once? if any of textview has on OnClick method.

Comment: Added in the post, also, if I click a standard button, same error appears. Just to clarify.

Comment: can you change the function from protected to public as below
public void registerView(View view) {
     // ur code
}

from 
protected void registerView(View view) {
}

Comment: It worked! :) Thank you very much surya! I am not sure to understand why I can't access protected methods from my views, but it works! You saved ma on this!

Comment: its the function prototype android looks for its looking for a public method.
Please check the link "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by simply changing the visibility of my methods called by onClick from protected to public.

```
public void registerView(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick for the docs that state this requirement.